# Use Autolayout for Child View Controllers

Tags: swift, autolayout, stack, uistackview

I am having trouble with auto layout again...

Here's what I want to get in the end:

[image: design]

I am doing everything in code with a Parent View Controller and Child View Controllers top, center and bottom.

In the end, I want to be able to set the height of the top view controller to its intrinsic height – that's where I am failing at right now... The top view controller has a vertical stack view used to place the elements (to be able to add and remove views as needed in the end).

This implementation...

```
import UIKit

class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var topChildView: UIView = {
        let topView = topChildViewController.view!
        topView.backgroundColor = .red
        topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        topView.accessibilityIdentifier = "top"
        return topView
    }()

    lazy var topChildViewController: TopChildViewController = {
        let topVC = TopChildViewController()
        return topVC
    }()

    lazy var centerChildView: UIView = {
        let centerView = centerChildViewController.view!
        centerView.backgroundColor = .blue
        centerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        centerView.accessibilityIdentifier = "center"
        return centerView
    }()

    lazy var centerChildViewController: CenterChildViewController = {
        let centerVC = CenterChildViewController()
        return centerVC
    }()

    lazy var bottomChildView: UIView = {
        let bottomView = bottomChildViewController.view!
        bottomView.backgroundColor = .green
        bottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bottomView.accessibilityIdentifier = "bottom"
        return bottomView
    }()

    lazy var bottomChildViewController: BottomChildViewController = {
        let bottom = BottomChildViewController()
        return bottom
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .gray

        self.addChild(topChildViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(topChildView)

        self.addChild(centerChildViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(centerChildView)

        self.addChild(bottomChildViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(bottomChildView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            topChildView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 12),
            topChildView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
            topChildView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
            topChildView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: topChildView.intrinsicContentSize.height),

            centerChildView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topChildView.bottomAnchor),
            centerChildView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topChildView.leadingAnchor),
            centerChildView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topChildView.trailingAnchor),

            bottomChildView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topChildView.leadingAnchor),
            bottomChildView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topChildView.trailingAnchor),
            bottomChildView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            bottomChildView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerChildView.bottomAnchor),
            bottomChildView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -12),
        ])
    }

}

class TopChildViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let s = UIStackView()
        s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        s.axis = .vertical
        s.distribution = .fillEqually
        s.spacing = 6
        return s
    }()

    lazy var textField: UITextField = {
        let t = UITextField()
        t.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        t.placeholder = "Some fancy text"
        t.accessibilityIdentifier = "textfield"
        t.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return t
    }()

    lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.accessibilityIdentifier = "label"
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        l.text = "Awesome Label"
        l.textAlignment = .center
        return l
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()

        view.addSubview(stackView)

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(textField)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([


            textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 12),
            textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
            textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),

            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -12)
        ])
    }
}

class CenterChildViewController: UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
    }
}

class BottomChildViewController: UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
    }
}
```

...leads to this outcome:

[image: outcome]

While I am aware of the error (the intrinsic height does not seem to be available at the time I am trying to access it, see below), I don't know how to resolve it – what am I missing?

Does the constraint need to get created someplace else? I'd really like to be able to have control over it from the parent view controller...

> ```
> [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>   Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
> you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to
> figure out which you don't expect;        (2) find the code that added the
> unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.  (
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002306d50 top.height == - 1   (active, names: top:0x7f81c1e1f120 )>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
> <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002306d50 top.height == - 1   (active, names:
> top:0x7f81c1e1f120 )>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
> to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
> UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
> <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
> ```

Comment: Wow, that's annoying: after accepting a change of format of some of my post by someone else, rather unimpressingly now my inline screenshots are missing and I can't figure out how to re-add them –– sorry for that!

Comment: Thanks for editing / resolving the pictures issue, @Yonat

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around, I do realise that I have to omit `topChildView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: topChildView.intrinsicContentSize.height),`
 entirely to make it work...

So the constraints I am providing in `ParentViewController.viewDidLoad()` are as follows:

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            topChildView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 12),
            topChildView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
            topChildView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),

            centerChildView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topChildView.bottomAnchor),
            centerChildView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topChildView.leadingAnchor),
            centerChildView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topChildView.trailingAnchor),

            bottomChildView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topChildView.leadingAnchor),
            bottomChildView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topChildView.trailingAnchor),
            bottomChildView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            bottomChildView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerChildView.bottomAnchor),
            bottomChildView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -12),
        ])
```